# Using Ranges in OR function (EXCEL)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am learning how to use excel in school, my teacher has assigned a problem where we have to use OR to solve a problem that says:

"Show TRUE if any number is under 1500" (using OR)

These are 4 cells that are `C7-F7` and the formula i used was `=OR(C7:F7<1500)`
Teacher says its wrong, says that we have to do `=OR(C7<1500,D7<1500,E7<1500,F7<1500)`

Teacher says that ranges shouldn't be used with the OR function, it works for me, and i looked around on the internet anywhere where it says using ranges in OR is wrong, found nothing, so i had to ask here, thank you all.

Comment: There is nothing wrong that I know of with `=OR(C7:F7<1500)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - I think it needs CSE'd in older versions of Excel tho, right?

Comment: @BigBen no, it should work as is without CSE.

Comment: No work for me.... `#VALUE!`. Office Professional Plus 2016.

Comment: For the layperson, that's `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` to enter it as an array function. `=OR(C7:F7<1500)` works for me (without CSE) on Excel for Mac v16.41.

Comment: hmmm you are correct it does require it.

Comment: @BigBen which is interesting as `=OR(C7={700,5000,2000})` works without CSE.

Comment: @ScottCraner - yes. That is quite interesting.

Comment: @BigBen found it: `=OR(N(IF({1},C7:F7))<1700)` does not require CSE and will work in older versions.

Answer (score 3):

Both you and your teacher are correct. Why? Because it depends on the Excel version.

In Excel 365, you can enter your formula. In previous versions of Excel, your formula will return an error, unless you know about array formulas and use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to confirm the formula.

Maybe your teacher can learn something from you today.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.